# The last commit of a file in git shows lines added but the file is not in the project folder

Tags: git, git-log

Using the command `git log --numstat` I can see that the last commit for the file **MyFile** shows some lines added. Which means that the last thing it has been done to **MyFile** is that somebody has added some lines to it.

At the same time I can not find **MyFile** in the project folder. Therefore I assume that **MyFile** is referenced in some branches but not in the current branch.

Is this a correct assumption? If so, is there a way to find which branches actually have references to **MyFile**?

Comment: `git log` should by default show the log from your current commit and backwards, so it should show the commits leading up to your current working folder status. Is there a possibility you have deleted the file locally? What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: add `--graph` to make sense of the output of `git log` : `git log --graph --numstat`. You will see clearly important information, such as the one described by TTT : there probably is a merge commit which joined two branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be explained if the following occurred:

1. The file was deleted on branch A.
2. The same file was modified on branch B *after* the deletion occurred (timewise).
3. Branch B is merged into branch A, which resulted in a conflict, and the deletion was selected.

Here's an example bash script to demonstrate this:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

git init

echo asdf > asdf.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Add file asdf.txt"

git branch test-branch

rm asdf.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Delete asdf.txt"

git switch test-branch

sleep 1 # pause for one second to make sure commit datetimes are different

echo qwer >> asdf.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Add qwer to asdf.txt"

git switch main

git merge test-branch --strategy=ours --no-edit # cheat to prevent a conflict and skip the other commit

ls -la # prove there are no files

git log --numstat # the most recent commit of asdf.txt is adding a line
```

Comment: Right, this was exactly the case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [Lasse V. Karlsen said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382731/the-last-commit-of-a-file-in-git-shows-lines-added-but-the-file-is-not-in-the-pr#comment122633975_69382731), by default, `git log` starts from the current or `HEAD` commit, and then works backwards from there.  So:

```
$ git log
commit cefe983a320c03d7843ac78e73bd513a27806845 (HEAD -> master ...
...
5       0       Documentation/RelNotes/2.34.0.txt

commit 45d141a1ddbc55c220ad4c726c02bbbf7a69247a
  :
  :

commit 187fc8b8b6e7a2b65f7c74cfaa8aa6bad36a18b2
...
29      15      unicode-width.h
```

Here we see that `unicode-width.h` was modified in commit `187fc8b8b6e7a2b65f7c74cfaa8aa6bad36a18b2`.  Just read upwards a bit from the numstat output to find the commit hash ID where, based on the result of `git diff`, the parent-vs-child has the given change to the given file.

> At the same time I can not find **MyFile** in the project folder. Therefore I assume that **MyFile** is referenced in some branches but not in the current branch.

*Branches* (branch names) are irrelevant; only *commits* matter.  Each commit is on zero or more branches, so commit `187fc8b8b6e7a2b65f7c74cfaa8aa6bad36a18b2` could be on 27 branches, or just on `master` (it's definitely on `master` since my `git log` started from `HEAD` which *names* `master`).  The file `unicode-width.h` is definitely in that commit.

Whether a file is in your *working tree* is also not really relevant, but if a file `MyFile` *isn't* in your working tree, running:

```
git log MyFile
```

will usually give you an error.  However:

```
git log -- MyFile
```

will not give you an error.  The reason is that here, `git log` knows to use `MyFile` as a path name:

```
$ rm Makefile
$ git log Makefile
fatal: ambiguous argument 'Makefile': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Git is trying to treat `Makefile` as a hash ID (it can't be one: it has some bad letters in it; `badf00d` or `deadcab` or `feedc0ffee` could be an abbreviated hash ID, but `c0mmand0` cannot be because neither `m` nor `n` are valid hexadecimal digits), or as a branch or tag name (but it isn't one), or some other way of finding a commit: see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for some of the many, *many* ways to specify particular commits.  The `--` syntax, however, tells Git commands that what follows is *not* an option, even if it resembles one, and in this case *not* a revision specifier either.  So `git log` now treats it as a file name:

```
$ git log -- Makefile
commit 8f79fb6445cb1d17c5527ba958e460725e7b111e
Merge: 68658a867d 32da6e6daf
Author: Junio C Hamano ...
```

(and of course I can restore the file I removed with `git restore` or `git checkout` or `git reset --hard` or whatever, which I did since I do not really want to remove it).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I still not able to understand what happens. I run `git log --numstat` and therefore the command starts from the current commit which in my case is master. In the `numstat` output I find **MyFile** with some lines added. Then which is the reason I do not find **MyFile** in my *current tree*? What happened to that file? To be more concrete, I found this case in the repo https://github.com/corona-warn-app/cwa-app-ios and the file that worries me is `src/xcode/ENA/ENAUITests/ExposureSubmission/ExposureSubmissionUITests.swift`.

Comment: Either you never had Git extract it, or you (or something else) told Git or something else to remove it after you had Git extract it. You can get the former if you use sparse checkout. You can get the latter in any way you like, including manually removing the file, having some random evil program conduct a drive-by-shooting and kill 17 files, etc.

Comment: The file is still there in the commit. It will always be in that commit. That commit cannot be changed, not by any power on Earth. As long as you have that commit, you have that file stored *in* that commit, and can extract it any time you like.